# Will a bootable USB drive work on a TV?

Tags: usb, tv, bootable-media

I have a USB flash drive with 32-bit Ubuntu Linux and an External Hard Drive with Windows 10 32-bit. What would happen if I were to plug 1 of these into a TV? Will it boot from the USB? Or will I only be able to view its files? Does it depend on TV type?

Comment: AFAIK the typical SoC used in TVs use a MIPS or ARM processor, which are completely incompatible with Intel processors.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your TV has an integrated Wintel-PC, you will be able to view the files only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would I know if it does? (I have Samsung Smart TV). Do I just plug it in and see what happens?

Comment: I think Samsung Smart TV always uses Android as operating system.

Comment: KK thx for the info

Answer (score 1):

In general if you plug a flash drive or external hard drive into a TV it won't boot, including an Android powered TV. If you plug a flash drive or external hard drive into a laptop, connect the laptop to the TV via a VGA/DVI/HDMI cable, and boot the laptop it will work even if the laptop screen is broken.

Some Android powered TVs have the ability of showing files that are stored on a flash drive.